# Using mybinder to display a jupyter notebook through appmode

Tags: jupyter

I'm trying to create a webpage to display my jupyter notebook output using appmode but it isn't working and I'm not sure why. Here is my repo: https://github.com/ryannchan123/EPRI

I've tried putting in my repo to my binder but it isn't able to output a webpage and I'm not quite sure why.

Comment: Your post description is quite vague. 'It isn't working' leaves a little to be desired. Instead I went to the official Appmode page and tried launching from the 'launch binder' badge there. I see just a blank page there and the app never loads? Is that what you see in your case from your launch too? Because I know a thing or two, I was able to get the official main example to open from within the session. So it may just be the current URL triggered by the 'launch binder' badge at the official site needs some adjusting in order to make it work with the current MyBinder infrastructure. A few ...

Comment: <continued> months ago, the default interface and how the URLs forward for MyBinder got slightly adjusted and not all the ramifications have been sorted out. I think Appmode may be one of the cases where that has impacted but nobody caught it yet since Voila is generally favored now. I'll need more time to explore if just adjusting the launch URL by hand can bypass the issue with the official site for now. Even if that is the case, it may be more prudent to ask the MyBinder folks to update the MyBinder side to work with the style of link the official site uses before changing all sites ...

Comment: <continued> using Appmode.  That too would need to be explored. In the future when you are using something like this and the official development site offers 'launch binder', make sure that works before investing a lot of time troubleshooting your own variation of the use of it via a launch binder link. Or at least compare what you are seeing vs what you see using that for launch and include that in your post for reference.

Comment: As for your repo.... Because I know a few things about how the URLs work, I was able to get to first open Jupyter for your repo via MyBinder and then switch to classic mode and then to Appmode for your site. Despite your configutation file situation being super complex, I'm seeing in Appmode rendering for you notebook `Ryan_Alex_EPRI_Final_Notebook.ipynb`, the following error: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'seaborn'`. I'm unsure which configuration file you expect MyBinder to use. Ideally with a complex set-up like you have, you'd put the mybinder configuration file and `postBuild` ...

Comment: <continued> in a `binder` sub-directory like [the official Appmode repo](https://github.com/oschuett/appmode) uses. It makes it much easier to debug things like this because ideally you don't want to pin versions for MyBinder to have the best chance to work the longest. Just list the special packages you need in either `requirements.txt`- or `environment.yml` - form without version specifications and only add those if something is problematic. This will let your repo wit MyBInder for the longest time because you won't mess up the packages it already comes with and usually it will get  ....

Comment: <continued> the latest set of packages that all work together best as the months go by. This approach has the best chance of allowing your repo continuing to work in conjunction with MyBinder. And, **importantly**, by using the `binder` sub-directory for that, you can still use your repo with other non-MyBinder tech and elsewhere as you see fit.

Answer (score 0):

I've posted [an issue here](https://github.com/oschuett/appmode/issues/75) because even the example launch from the Appmode repo isn't working to go directly to Appmode view as did in the past.

For now there is a clunky work around to still use the Appmode view.

#### Temporary work around to use Appmode in a MyBinder-launched session

If you first launch into the Jupyter session so the token is established in your session, you can use Appmode subsequently.

For your case, you'd launch with the following URL:

```
https://mybinder.org/v2/gh/ryannchan123/EPRI/main?urlpath=%2Fnotebooks%2FRyan_Alex_EPRI_Final_Notebook.ipynb
```

Or [just click here](https://mybinder.org/v2/gh/ryannchan123/EPRI/main?urlpath=%2Fnotebooks%2FRyan_Alex_EPRI_Final_Notebook.ipynb) to try launching into Jupyter Notebook mode with your Jupyter notebook open.
**And then click on the 'Appmode' button along the top.**

**You'll note though that your environment currently has an issue where Seaborn isn't present.** I've discussed this in my comments because I don't think that was the main issue you were posting about.

#### The future 'solution' for launching directly to Appmode

Once the example Appmode repo has a working 'launch binder' badge that lets launches directly into Appmode-served via MyBinder sessions work again, we should be able to craft a URL for yours. (Or use the one you already tried.) And it should work again for directly launching into Appmode. In other words, I don't think there is a real solution that you can implement yourself to launch direct. You just have to be patient for now.

Once the